# No puedo llamar una función Javascript

Tags: jquery

```
var req_control;
clearTimeout(req_control);

function peticiones()
{
  clearTimeout(req_control);
  $.ajax({
    url:'php/control_administrativo/peticiones.php',
    method:'POST',
    success:function(data)
    {
      $('#peticiones').text(data);
    }
  });
  req_control = setTimeout(function(){ peticiones();}, 5000);
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
  if($('#nivel')==3)
  {
      peticiones();
  }
});
```

La función es llamada al estar lista la página, pero no lo vuelve a hacer ya nunca.
La línea `req_control = setTimeout(function(){ peticiones();}, 5000);` debería volver a llamar la función. ¿Qué estará mal?

Esto es lo que quiero modificar

```
        <?php
        if ($_SESSION["NIVEL"]>=1)
        {
        ?>
        <li>
          <a href="#" id="codificador">
          <img src="images/Iconos/Figuras_g.png" width="20" height="20"> Codificador Genesys
          <?php
              if ($_SESSION["NIVEL"]==3)
              {
                echo '<span class="badge" id="peticiones"></span>';
              }?>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php } ?>
```

Gracias a todos.

Comment: Menos mal que editaste. 3000000 son muchos !!

Comment: Si, una disculpa, igual no entra la función ni con 1ms

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir también tu html?

Comment: No veo mucha información con el HTML, anexo la parte que se tiene que actualizar.

Comment: estas seguro seguro que no se lanza? probaste con un console log antes de la funcion? puede que el problema sea dle ajax y al no tener .error para evaluar dificil ver si entra o no

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob Sí, por supuesto era para ver la parte a la que se refería el código.

Comment: Y si cambias el `setTimeout( function( ) { peticiones( ) } )` por `setTimeout( function( ) { window.peticiones( ); } )` ??

Comment: Pregunta... Que le envías al Ajax?  `data`

Comment: No le envío nada al Ajax, este me regresa un número, y si está entrando, por que al momento de que se termina de cargar la página si me trae el número, el problema es que no lo vuelve a hacer.

Comment: Y un load no te sirve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quita

```
req_control = setTimeout(function(){ peticiones();}, 1000);
```

Y deja solo `setTimeout(function(){ peticiones();}, 1000);`

```js
function peticiones()
{
  var data = "3";
  $('#peticiones').text(data + $('#peticiones').text());
  setTimeout(function(){ peticiones();}, 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
  peticiones();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="peticiones"></span>
```

Comment: Ya lo hice, pero igual no jala, de hecho quité var req_control;
clearTimeout(req_control); de todos lados y aún así no funciona :(

Comment: ejecuta mi snippet @AlbertoSiurob

Comment: Ya salío gracias, estoy trabajando con Chrome y nunca actualizó el script, lo intenté con Firefox y si funciona, pero el Chrome en los Sources parece como si el script no se hubiese actualizado.

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob Prueba a eliminar la caché. Hay veces que puede generar problemas.

Comment: me alegro @AlbertoSiurob y gracias Error404 por la acotación, me ganaste :3

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no deberias asignar nada a `req_control` deberia ser algo como:

```js
function peticiones() {
    clearTimeout(req_control);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/control_administrativo/peticiones.php',
        method: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#peticiones').text(data);
        }
    });
    
    setTimeout(function() {
        peticiones();
    }, 5000);
}
```